# change rounded RelativeLayout background image

Tags: android

I have ListViewAdapter that each item is RelativeLayout.
I want that each item will have different rounded image but i cant figure out how to change the image .

My drawable xml look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/item2">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners  android:radius="5dip" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

 <item android:id="@+id/item">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
 </item>

</layer-list>
```

And my code look like this :

```
LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)m_context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_border);
    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.item2,GetDrawableFromUrl(prod.getImageUrl()));
    RelativeLayout raw = (RelativeLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.raw);
    raw.setBackgroundDrawable(ld);
```

But the result is that image without the rounded edges and the stroke .

How do i change the image without damage the rounded edges and the stroke ?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to set `item` and not `item2` to the image?

Comment: Its is dose not work either . Same result , the image is override the edges and the stroke .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If round rect image is to be set as background for each item in the list. Check it out [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/).

Comment: Thanks , works great ! But I want that the image is bigger than the rectangle , how do i scale the size of the image ?

Comment: @user2102843: Probably it's another ques, to be posted as new ques!  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Your Bitmap, destination width, destination height, Whether to set filter) does the job.